# returning column from a std vector of fusion vectors, without copying

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming, boost-fusion

I have a "table" represented by a `std::vector` where every element is a `boost::fusion::vector`. I need to return a representation of a "column" of this table as a `std::vector`, without copying any values over. What is the best way of doing this? I am trying to construct a `std::vector` of nviews where n is the column number, but it does not seem to be working. Am I on the right track or are there other ways of going about this?

Comment: Can you use C++11 or are you limited to C++03?

Comment: I guess I'm ok with either, but I'd like to know what the difference would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence/concepts/random_access_sequence.html), the `at<N>(s)` method of the `boost::fusion::vector`'s return a reference to the contained element.

Also if you are using boost library version 1.48, they support the move semantics of C++11. What this means is you can have a function which loops over the size of your table for a particular column no, say `i`, and populates a column vector which is an `std::vector`. You then just return this column vector and the calling function would get the `move`d `std::vector`. No copies are made at any point.

You can read more about the [move semantics here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html#Move_Semantics) at the standards page itself. You can also watch the video of [Bjarne Stroustrup explaining it in brief here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style). Jump to minute 37 and watch till minute 43.